# TYPO3 updateAction not called

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18
that's my action. When I submit form this action not called!

```
  /**
     * action update
     *
     * @param \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User $user
     */
    public function updateAction(\Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User $user) {

        die();

    }
```

but this varian works, when I set another type.

```
    /**
     * action update
     *
     * @param array $user
     */
    public function updateAction(array $user) {
//        var_dump($user);
        die();
//        parent::updateAction($user);
    }
```

Where may be problem? People help please. I really have not any ideas (

Comment: What kind of errors it shows?
also check that Object argument you are passing in form.

Comment: This happened becaue in update action you need to pass user object, but you can pass user array.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because I did't set right converter for my 'date' field.

Comment: Did this also solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138896/typo3-femanager-update-method-not-called?